# Using window function quantity until total consumed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been researching CTE with window functions trying to determine if it's possible to update inventory quantity records with an order quantity until the order quantity is consumed without recursive method because of window functions introduced in sql server
i have found best solutions
here [CTE - recursively update quantity until total consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843129/cte-recursively-update-quantity-until-total-consumed)

But it is very complex to understand for beginners like me..Please any one convert to Cte with window function will very helpfull..
i have tried window function to calculate Running quantity..But not succeded.. i am using Sql sevrer 2012..Pls  help me to convert the solutions in window function without recursive

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myOrder](
  [Account] [float] NOT NULL,
  [Item] [float] NOT NULL,
  [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into dbo.myOrder values (12345, 1, 50)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myInventory](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Account] [float] NOT NULL,
  [InvDate] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
  [Item] [float] NOT NULL,
  [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
  [QuantitySold] [float] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into dbo.myInventory values (12345, 111287, 1, 45, 40)
insert into dbo.myInventory values (12345, 111290, 1, 40, 0)
insert into dbo.myInventory values (12345, 111290, 1, 12, 0)
insert into dbo.myInventory values (12345, 111291, 1, 25, 0)


Expected Result:

ID  Account Item    QuantitySoldNew
1   12345   1         5
2   12345   1        40
3   12345   1         5
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,,,i have updated link of the solution..

Comment: why do you need a CTE?  This can be done with a simple `group by` Your sample data doesn't reflect the result data

Comment: wait, this is the exact question that you linked to.  What are you doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTE - recursively update quantity until total consumed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843129/cte-recursively-update-quantity-until-total-consumed)

Comment: yes..i need a solution in window functions without recursive method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `SUM Over(Order by)`  window function

```
SELECT Id,
       Account,
       InvDate,
       Item,
       QuantitySoldNew = CASE
                           WHEN run_tot < 0 THEN ( [Quantity] - [QuantitySold] ) + run_tot
                           ELSE diff
                         END
FROM   (SELECT mi.*,
               diff=mi.[Quantity] - [QuantitySold],
               run_tot = mo.[Quantity]
                         + Sum(( mi.[Quantity] - [QuantitySold]) *-1)OVER(partition BY mo.account ORDER BY id)
        FROM   [myInventory] mi
               JOIN myOrder mo
                 ON mi.Account = mo.Account
                    AND mi.Item = mo.Item) a
WHERE  CASE WHEN run_tot < 0 THEN ( [Quantity] - [QuantitySold] ) + run_tot ELSE diff END > 0
```